# Firebase data structure for one to chat app or private

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I am developing a web applications where i need to add chat functionality. A user publish his product, and another user interested can chat with the seller to stay or know more details about product.

I got stuck on implantation of chat, I can't find out a suitable data structure for need. 
My need is; let's say John is the seller and publish his phone to sell. Charles got interest on John phone's and he want to know more details about that, so start chatting with John. They don't know each other before chatting, not like WhatsApp. Where a user know another user before send a message. 
John could have published so many products and Charles could interest on different products of him, for each product will create a new conversation (chat).

I want that, if john delete a message, then that should delete from his chat not from Charles.

The chat is private or one to one.

Until now i have done this data structure. I don't know if it is the best way? please suggest me

```
chats
    sender_ID _ Reciever_id
        product_id
            message:''
            Timestamp:''
            SenderName:''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user publishes a product (the potential seller), you'll need to associate their user ID with that product. Based on that, the interested user (potential buyer) can make the connection.

Given your other requirements, I'd nest the chats:

```
chats: {
  uid1_uid2_productid: {
    pushid: { message: ..., timestamp: ..., sender: ... },
    pushid: { message: ..., timestamp: ..., sender: ... }
  }
}
```

And then associate these chats with the correct users in user-specific lists:

```
user_chats: {
  uid1: {
    uid1_uid2_productid: true
  },
  uid2: {
    uid1_uid2_productid: true
  }
}
```

Instead of `true` you could also store a value (or more properties) that help you display the list of chats for that specific user.

---

If you want each user to have a completely separate copy of the chat/room, your easiest approach is to duplicate the rooms. So:

```
chats: {
  uid1_uid2_productid: {
    pushid: { message: ..., timestamp: ..., sender: ... },
    pushid: { message: ..., timestamp: ..., sender: ... }
  }
  uid2_uid1_productid: {
    pushid: { message: ..., timestamp: ..., sender: ... },
    pushid: { message: ..., timestamp: ..., sender: ... }
  }
}
```

And then:

```
user_chats: {
  uid1: {
    uid1_uid2_productid: true
  },
  uid2: {
    uid2_uid1_productid: true
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping. I am confused about the nested chat. Why i have to do it. What else properties should i store there? Please need help. I have my product data structure like this  
 `user
    user_id
 product
  prodcut_id
   products:
     title:’’
    description:’’`

Comment: As said: the `user_chats` JSON structure associates the chats with individual users. After signing a user in, you'd start with reading this structure for their UID (`/user_chats/$uid`) to determine what chats/rooms to show to them. The information you include here, is whatever information you need to display to the user in that initial list of chats/rooms. Then once the user clicks on an individual chat/room, you load the full list of messages from the relevant `/chats/$roomid` node.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The problem with that is if the `uid1` deletes a message, it won't appear in the `uid2` chat. Because you associate the actual (original) chat with both users.

Comment: You really want them unmodified? That's highly unusual. But if you do, you'll have to create separate chat rooms for each user. So you'd have `uid1_uid2_productid` and `uid2_uid1_productid`. I updated my answer to show the JSON for that.